# How to change the keyvalue's target value constantly in a javafx Timeline?

Tags: java, animation, javafx, bind

Instead of giving a fixed value as a target is there any way to continuously change the keyvalues's target value while the animation is running.

To achieve this goal I have bound the target value with a node's width property which changes continuously.But bind is not working at all when the animation starts the target value doesn't update and stuck.

This is the code for the animation

```
public void setGlowAnimation(){
    System.out.println("WIDTH "+width.getValue());
    KeyValue value = new KeyValue(glowshape.centerXProperty(),width.getValue(),Interpolator.EASE_OUT);

    KeyFrame keyframe1 = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(2000),value);

    glow_timeline = new Timeline();
    glow_timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
    glow_timeline.setAutoReverse(true);
    glow_timeline.getKeyFrames().add(keyframe1);
}



public void init(){
    indetermination();
    setStartAnimation();
    createEllipse();

    width = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
   width.bind(this.widthProperty());
   setGlowAnimation();
}
```

Comment: Do you ever call `glow_timeline.play()`? I don't see it anywhere in your code.

Comment: yes, I did call the glow_timeline.play() in the task method that I didn't include here actually.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can modify a `Timeline` while it is active like that. Consider using a `Transition` instead:

```
import javafx.animation.Animation;
import javafx.animation.Interpolator;
import javafx.animation.Transition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class AdaptiveAnimation extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Circle circle = new Circle(0, 100, 25, Color.CORNFLOWERBLUE);
        Pane pane = new Pane(circle);

        Interpolator interp = Interpolator.EASE_BOTH ;

        Transition transition = new Transition() {
            {
                setCycleDuration(Duration.millis(2000));
            }

            @Override
            protected void interpolate(double frac) {
                double x = interp.interpolate(0, pane.getWidth(), frac);
                circle.setCenterX(x);
            }

        };
        transition.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
        transition.setAutoReverse(true);

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 600, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        transition.play();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

This is a little jumpy while you're resizing the window, but it provides the basic idea.

Comment: Thanx a lot, I definitely try transition later. But fortunately, I've solved the problem by using a little trick.What I did is instead of setting  glow_timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE) I set it to glow_timeline.setCycleCount(1) and added a handler which triggers after animation ends and executes the setGlowAnimation() method again and starts the animation.

Comment: By taking this approach now every time a new timeline objects produces runs for 1 cycle and then triggers a handler which creates a new timeline object with updated key value and plays that. It might not be the good coding approach but it solved the problem anyway.....